# Macdonald-Koornwinder polynomials?

Tags: special-functions

Does Mathematica have an internal implementation of the [Macdonald-Koornwinder polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koornwinder_polynomials)? (Also called Koornwinder polynomials.) I looked online but could not find it.

Comment: Given that the creator of these polynomials uses Mathematica: http://community.wolfram.com/web/thkoornwinder I sent him an email asking him directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer comes directly from Tom Koornwinder:

> I tried to post the following answer:
>
> ---
>
> There is certainly no internal implementation of these polynomials in
>   Mathematica. Neither there is an external implementation, as far as I
>   know. Of course, one can pose similar questions about Macdonald and
>   Jacobi (Heckman-Opdam) polynomials for any root system, in particular
>   BC. Of course, most has been done for root system A (Jack,
>   Hall-Littlewood and Macdonald), but mostly in Maple. See:
>
> [John Stembridge's SF package](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~jrs/maple.html#SF), (see also his paper)
>
> [MOPS package](http://www.math.washington.edu/~dumitriu/mopspage.html) by
>   Ioana Dumitriu et al. (see also their paper)
>
> [Mike Zabrocki's webpage](http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/MPWP/maplefuncs.html)
>
> Some Mathematica routines were written by [Wendy Baratta](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/~wbaratta/index.html),
>   but she is no longer active in research.
>
> [Per Alexandersson](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/) claims on
>   [Change of basis of polynomials](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109373/change-of-basis-of-polynomials) to have some Mathematica code for Macdonald polynomials
>
> Tom Koornwinder
>
> ---
>
> but it was refused because I give too many links, while I have not yet
>   built up reputation on mathematica.stackexchange.
>
> Can you possibly post it on behalf of me?

Comment: The difficulty as far as I can tell is that these polynomials require an implementation of a multivariate version of `QHypergeometricPFQ[]`, which we don't have yet.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get access to Dr. Wendy Baratta's SpecialFuncionts.nb mathematica notebook?

Comment: Also, does anyone know her contact address (email)? Her Melbourne university contact address seems to have expired.