# Mathematica package for computing Macdonald polynomials

Tags: polynomials, code-request, algebra

I want to implement computation of Macdonald polynomials in mathematica. A similar question was raised in another question 5 years ago ([Macdonald-Koornwinder polynomials?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111268/macdonald-koornwinder-polynomials)), but received no clear answer.

I am aware of Wendy Baratta's work (especially https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4450v1) which contains Mathematica notebook for computing Macdonald polynomials.

More precisely, in the paper cited above, she wrote a Mathematica notebook called SpecialFunctions.nb and was once downloadable in ( [www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/wbaratta/index.html](http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/wbaratta/index.html)), but the homepage is removed, probably because she left academia (although not certain).

Does anyone have access to that notebook, or has contact address of her (her Belbourne university email has expired), or have other mathematica packages that was developed in the last 5 years? (I would also welcome other sources for other languages, in addition to those listed in the other SE question linked above.)